# Word Wrap in ICSharpcode TextEditor

Tags: c#, text-editor, icsharpcode

I'm using the ICSharpcode text editor, and I am looking for a way to do Word Wrap in it.  Is there any documentation for this other than the source code?  My only documentation so far has been the [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextEditorControl.aspx), and the source code for [Kaxaml](http://www.codeplex.com/Kaxaml/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx).  Most importantly, how does one turn WordWrap on in the editor?  Second, is there any documentation that I am missing for the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ICSharpCode.TextEditor` does not support word wrapping yet. It will support it in SharpDevelop 4. See [this forum post](http://community.icsharpcode.net/forums/p/8879/24725.aspx#24725), among [others](http://community.icsharpcode.net/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=word+wrap&o=Relevance). You can download SharpDevelop 4 Alpha from their [build server](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/BuildArtefacts/).

In order to implement support for word wrapping yourself, you're gonna have to jump through a lot of hoops. And these hoops will all be on fire. If you ***really*** need this, in SharpDevelop 3, a good place to look for the code to word-wrap is [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.co.uk/show/4646/) as Jon T suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found this information about the editor:

http://community.icsharpcode.net/forums/p/100/19865.aspx

The poster wasn't sure about native word wrap support, but provides a link to a wrapper that handles word wrapping:

http://www.developerfusion.co.uk/show/4646/

Comment: Yeah, I already found that, however it is just a generic class to split lines.  I don't know how to hook it into the Text Editor, and neither the forum comment or anywhere shows me how.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, the documentation on this seems a bit sparse. :(

Answer (score 0):

Word wrapping is very hard to get right and still have the renderer fast.